How to install ROS on Intel Galileo
I got an old Intel Galileo (Gen 2) board and found an article about installing ROS on it.
After a while of research, I couldn’t find any useful downloads for it.
I am looking for an SD Image with Yocto kernel or at least something Debian alike to install ROS.
Everything is already outdated, and the links are dead or not useful because it requires building a new kernel and there are no step-by-step guides for it.
I would be thankful for a link to download or at least for an absolute beginner tutorial.

For an old platform I would expect that most of the documentation relevant is also likely older as well. Please revise your question to include what you've tried and why it's not working for you such that someone here can help you make it work potentially. Rather than just stating that it's not working for you. I'm you're looking at a platform and yocto builds it's standard to your own images from the ground up for your platform. This is likely a choice which will make your learning curve a lot steeper.

Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the Robotics question checklist to edit your question to make it better scoped.
